# django admin. create a custom autocomplete field when adding MTM links to admin.TabularInline

Tags: django, django-admin

I have three django models.

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(_('user_id'), primary_key=True, blank=False)
    permission = models.CharField(_('permission'), max_length=30, choices=UserPermissionType.choices)
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255)
    chat_id = models.BigIntegerField(_('chat_id'), )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'
        verbose_name = _('User')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Users')


class Store(models.Model):
    store_id = models.AutoField(_('store_id'), primary_key=True)
    store_name = models.CharField(_('store_name'), unique=True, max_length=150)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='StoreUser')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.store_name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'stores'
        verbose_name = _('Store')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Stores')


class StoreUser(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey('Store', models.DO_NOTHING)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'stores_users'
        unique_together = (('store', 'user'),)
```

I am trying to make it so that when adding a store to a user on the user's page in the TabularInline field, I would see a drop-down list with lines like f"{store_id}: {store_name}".
at the same time, I would like the autocomplete to work on this field

I've tried a lot of options. Now I have this variant, but I don't seem to understand at all how `AutocompleteSelect` works

```
class StoreAutocompleteField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    queryset = Store.objects.all()
    widget = AutocompleteSelect(StoreUser._meta.get_field('store').remote_field, admin.site)

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return f"{obj.id}: {obj.name}"


class UserStoreInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = StoreUser
    extra = 0
    verbose_name = _('Stores for user')

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "store":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Store.objects.all()
            kwargs["form_class"] = StoreAutocompleteField
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

I get this error: `'tuple' object has no attribute 'field'`

Comment: pick one [package for auto-complete](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/auto-complete/)